# How do I just get a list of JSON objects from RestSharp?

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I am calling a WinApi 2.0 server using RestSharp and I get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "ItemSubType": "Base"
    },
    {
        "ItemSubType": "Tall"
    },
    {
        "ItemSubType": "Uppers"
    }
]
```

I just need the three strings ["Base,"Tall","Uppers"].  What I would like is to get a list or array or enumerable sequence of `JsonObject` instances. The best that I have been able to do is get a `JsonArray` which is nothing more than a `List<Object>`.

I really don't want to have to create a class with a property named "ItemSubType" just to get these three values. How can I do this?

Comment: If you're willing to switch libraries, this is a one-liner with [Flurl](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http): `var list = await "http://myapi.com".GetJsonListAsync();` That gives you a list of dynamics, so you can get item.ItemSubType without having to declare a class.

Comment: Thanks. I stay away from libraries that use extension methods on strings. :p

Comment: Nah, I was kidding. This is interesting. I'm going to give this a try. Thanks.

Comment: Ha, one in every crowd. You can certainly new things up if you like it sugar-free :)

Comment: I'm just in a weird mood today. Yeah, someone should write a library called "saccharin" for people like me. When extension methods first came out, I drank the kool-aid that they were not efficient and should be avoided. Now they are all over the place. OWIN for crying out loud. Now I like them just fine. I just don't like dirtying my intellisense unnecessarily. I am going to look into your library. It looks really clean. I like that. Props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just need the three strings, then deserialize it as a list of dictionaries then use Linq to pick out the values:

```
var serializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
var list = serializer.Deserialize<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(json).SelectMany(d => d.Values).ToList();
```